# ClassNotFoundException when starting Spring Boot app that uses Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Java SpringBoot with Jetty and Cassandra. I followed the basic tutorial for setting up a RESTful server, but I'm getting an exception when i try to run the jar. Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/HttpConstraintElement
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:619)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:880)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:869)
at kikpay.Application.main(Application.java:16)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/HttpConstraintElement
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.HttpConstraintElement
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:103)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 16 more
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.0.RC4")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'example'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    compile("com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

I am new to Spring, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The class `javax.servlet.HttpConstraintElement` was added in Servlet 3.0. Check if your jetty servlet container is at that version.

Comment: Maybe Cassandra depends transitively on an old version of the servlet spec?

Comment: What is really weird, is that the server runs fine if I use "./gradlew bootRun" instead of running the jar directly.

Comment: Eh, I fixed it by just using tomcat (the default) instead of jetty. Would still like to understand why it didn't work, but now it isn't important.

Comment: I have seen this happen when using jetty in Spring Boot and having another dependency (indirect or not) that drags an older version of jetty (or anything else that could drag an older version of javax.servlet). This conflict can usually be exposed by checking the dependency hierarchy. -- my 2 cents :)